# How to tell Terminal which version of Ruby to use?

Tags: ruby, macos

I have two related questions that I was hoping someone could help out with.

1. I recently installed Ruby 1.9.2 on my Mac (running Snow Leopard 10.6.4) and I haven’t been able to figure out how to get Terminal to use the new Ruby as a default, rather than the factory-installed Ruby 1.8.7.  The old Ruby 1.8.7 is located in my `~/usr/bin/ruby` directory while the new Ruby 1.9.2 is in `~/usr/local/bin/ruby`.  Someone said that I need to put the new version of Ruby's directory in the PATH prior to the old version's directory so that the system looks there first - is this correct?  If so, can anyone provide step by step instructions on how to do this?
2. I’ve created a new directory but can’t seem to figure out the correct way to add that directory to my PATH using the Terminal bash shell.  I tried using the instructions that I found here (http://www.macgasm.net/2008/04/10/ad...thin-terminal/) twice but they didn't work for me.  The directory containing my program ("Ruby_Programs") shows up in the PATH but when I try to run "ruby newprogram.rb" from the command line it results in `":ruby: No such file or directory -- newprogram.rb (LoadError)"`.  The file definitely exists and is a functional Ruby program.  I did change the name of the directory to "Ruby Programs" and then back to "Ruby_Programs" - could that have somehow caused this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my current PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/sbrriffe/src:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/sbriffe/Ruby_Programs/:
```

Answer (score 12):

You might want to check out [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). You can install multiple versions of ruby side by side and easily switch between them. If you follow the rvm installation notes you won't have any more path problems.

Comment: This link is abit easier, please check it out http://amerine.net/2010/02/24/rvm-rails3-ruby-1-9-2-setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Your Ruby Programs directory shouldn't be in your path: the location of your ruby interpreter should be. Then, you `cd` to the location of your ruby program, and run it from there: `ruby program.rb`.

Since you are on a Mac, check out [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) for something that will make installing software easier. I have my homebrew set up in `/usr/local`, and it works great.

Once you have installed stuff where you need it, then you'll want to adjust your `$PATH`. The items in `$PATH` are searched in the order they appear, so in your `~/.bashrc`, you'll want to add:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

To make sure `/usr/local/bin` gets searched before `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use RVM to get everything installed, and then once you have RVM installed it is easy to set your default Ruby version.

Check out https://rvm.io/ -- once you have that installed you can change your default by using : $ rvm use 1.9.2 --default

hope that helps- you can do this with any version, not only 1.9.2